# What Google's Anthos with Kubernetes can do and how does it fits in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-anthos

I understand from [official Docs](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/) Anthos is built on Kubernetes/Istio/Knative but where does Anthos fits in Google cloud platform.

Can it act as configuration manager for application auto-deployment, provisioning etc ?

Does it provide support for language specific build on the fly?

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for Stackoverflow. You are asking for opinions. Both companies have significant amounts of documentation on their products, including demos, videos, competitive positioning, etc. Spend the time to review those resources and form your own opinion. You might try Redit or Quora for this type of question.

Comment: That is what the documentation is for. Once you have a good understanding of a product, StackOverflow is the place to ask for answers to specific problems. Why would you think that an answer here would be better than all of the marketing and technical documentation that Google and Red Hat has written? Again, your question asks for opinions. Your question is not well defined and too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Anthos you can basically manage multiple Kubernetes clusters from multiple Clouds (Amazon, Google, Azure) and on-prem. It can help you maintain a hybrid environment and move in a predictable way or partially your infrastructure from on-prem to cloud.

You can use Anthos Config Management to create a common configuration for your clusters. You can use ClusterSelectors to apply configurations to subsets of clusters.
Configuration can include Istio service mesh, pod security policies, or quota policies.

From a security perspective, you can manage your policies using Anthos Policy Controller, enforcing PodSecurityPolicies, with the advantage of  testing constraints before enforcing them.